# Deletion of given matrix entry via matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Is it possible to define an operator $\phi(i,j)$ which, when applied to matrix $A$, will delete the $ij$-th element, so that $[ \phi(i,j) A ]_{i,j} = 0$?

If so, is it possible to define this operator in terms of the standard matrix product or the Kronecker product? If not, is there a proof that such an operator does not exist?

Comment: It's certainly not possible with a standard matrix product. If there was some $B$ such that $BA$ deletes a specified off-diagonal entry of $A$, then to find $B$, simply plug in $A = I$. Deleting an off-diagonal entry of $I$ produces $I$, so $I$ should be the same as $BI$, i.e. $B$. But the operation here is not the identity operation (it makes some changes), hence we cannot have $B = I$, a contradiction. Similarly, multiplying from the left won't work either, i.e. $A \mapsto AB$. Try thinking about what happens when you nullify an on-diagonal entry! Hint: it still won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for some $F$ such that $e_i^T FA e_j = 0$ for all $A$ and, for $(k,l) \neq (i,j)$,
$e_k^T FA e_l = e_k^T A e_l$ for all $A$.

Since $A$ is arbitrary, we have $e_i^T Fx = 0$ for all $x$ and so
$e_i^T F = 0$.

Choose $l \neq j$ and let $A=e_i e_l^T$, then $e_i^TFAe_l = e_i^TFe_i = 0$, but
we also required that $e_i^TFAe_l = e_i^TAe_l = 1$.

Hence no such $F$ is possible.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: If $F^Te_i = 0$ for all $i$ then $F^T = 0$!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Sorry, you are correct.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: I fixed the answer. The proof is very ugly for such an intuitive result.

Comment: Still, there's a linear transformation that does the job. And it can be written in terms of a matrix-vector product... if one vectorizes everything first.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Of course, the map from a matrix to one with the $i,j$ entry zero is clearly linear.

Answer (score 1):

One could use the (projection-like) linear operator $\Phi_{ij} : \mathbb R^{n \times n} \to \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ defined by

$$\Phi_{ij} ({\rm X}) := {\rm X} - {\rm e}_i^{\,} {\rm e}_i^\top {\rm X} \, {\rm e}_j^{\,} {\rm e}_j^\top$$

where ${\rm e}_i$ and ${\rm e}_j$ are the $i$-th and $j$-th vectors of the standard basis, respectively.

---

[linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) [linear-transformations](/questions/tagged/linear-transformations) [matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices)